# xmlElement vs xmlNode effects on memory

Tags: xml, vb.net, memory

I'm working in the performance of a large procedure which parses a XML file looking for some attributes, many times.

When I analyzed the whole proccess, I realized that there where a *for* loop which consumed 2MB of RAM memory each loop, it toke about 3GB RAM for the whole process, too inefficient according our objectives. Thats the code:

```
        For Each element As XmlElement In xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/disk")
            If element.Name = "object" Then
                If objectIdentifier = element.GetElementsByTagName("objectIdentifier").Item(0).InnerText Then
                    XMLObject_fileName = element.GetElementsByTagName("XMLObject_fileName").Item(0).InnerText
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
```

Here is when I saw the code was parsing using XmlElement class. I had usually worked only with xmlNode class, so I decided to change it, only to test. And when I executed with this change, the proccess "only" took barely 1GB of RAM memory.

Thats the new code:

```
        For Each element As XmlNode In xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/disk")
            If element.Name = "object" Then
                If objectIdentifier = element.SelectNodes("objectIdentifier").Item(0).InnerText Then
                    XMLObject_fileName = element.SelectNodes("XMLObject_fileName").Item(0).InnerText
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
```

So, my question is: Why this difference? Does anyone know how these classes use the memory?

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: When reading large Xml files you should always use an XmlReader which reads only a portion of the xml into memory rather than the entire file.  using XmlRead also runs quicker.  I've gotten reports that XmlReader ran 70% faster.  See my answer at following posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37750797/logic-to-reading-an-xml-file-in-vb-net/37753397#37753397

Comment: Your method 1 does a 'GET' while method 2 does a 'SELECT'.

Comment: I knew about XMLReader, but I have to fix quickly this issue, I have inherit this code, but thanks anyway, in fact we were considering this change before, but there is never enough time...

About GET vs SELECT, sorry about my ignorance, but, what's the difference. Thanks!